# Swift dictionary types

Tags: swift, types

I'm going crazy with swift,
I'm an expert Objective C developer and I try to do some basic things in swift but I'm getting crazy on types and ! and ?

In the following example, I'm doing a simple get where I get a json, and I want to convert the json["data"] to Account types:

But in the MAP I'm always getting compilation errors due invalid types, and when I was able to make it compile, then I get an exception...

Any idea on how should I proceed?

```
HTTP.GET(url, parameters: [], headers: headers) { response in
    do {
        let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: response.data, options: []) as! [String: Any]
        let accountsDict: NSArray = json["data"] as! NSArray;

        let accounts = accountsDict.map { (dict) -> Account in
            let dict2 = dict as! Dictionary<String, String>
            debugPrint(dict);
            return Account(name       : dict2["tenant"]!,
                           geolocation: dict2["geolocation"]!);
        }
        completion(accounts);
    }catch{
        print(error.localizedDescription)
        completion(nil);
    }

}
```

Comment: Please show your JSON response as text. And if you want to get familiar with Swift, you should better not use `NSArray`.

Comment: Do not use JSONSerialization. Use Decodable.

Comment: It looks like you're struggling with Optionals, among other things. You should take some time to read the Swift language guide, particularly the section on [Optionals](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/TheBasics.html#ID330). It might take some time to "click", but optionals are actually quite straight forward, and they solve a problem that you have most certainly run into, time and time again, as an ObjC developer. Optionals are a solution to the 4 code patterns I listed in this [reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/swift/comments/aubvhf/requiring_explicit_self/eh8e5ww)

Comment: To reiterate matt's comment, your pain is coming from JSONSerialization. It is very, very unlikely that you want to use that tool. It creates all the headaches you're encountering. You want to use a Decodable structure and JSONDecoder, which are designed to work with Swift very well. JSONSerialization only exists in Swift because it's bridged from ObjC.

Comment: Thank you for the info, looks like `JSONDecoder` might be what I need, however my response has a pagination, and I want to get the `data` field into `Account`s array, something easy like this

`accounts = response.data["data"].map(... return Account(...))`

and the JSONDecode forces me to decode it to an defined object but I would like the pagination object to first be a generic dictionary <String, Any>, but then any is not decodable...

Comment: Oookk.. creating an struct for the pagination solved the problem,
```
struct Pagination :Decodable{
    var data : Array<Account>;
}

------ 
        HTTP.GET(url, parameters: [], headers: headers) { response in
            do {
                let jsonDecoder = JSONDecoder()
                let accounts = try jsonDecoder.decode(Pagination.self, from: response.data)                
                completion(accounts.data);
            }catch{
                print(error.localizedDescription)
                completion(nil);
            }
            
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

**In simple words:**

`?` is an optional parameter, which prevents your code from crashing if your value is nil.

`!` forcefully unwrap the value which means by adding `!` you are making sure that your variable will have value and if it is `nil` then your code will crash, so do not use `!` in case if you are not sure about value.

**Type:**

In Swift 4, `[<key-Type>: <value-Type>]` is your dictionary in key-value format and `[<object-Type>]` is an array. For example:

```
    let dictionary: [String: String] = ["name": "Ankit", "Website": "Stack-Overflow"]
    let array: [String] = ["Ankit", "Mike", "Reynolds"]
```

You don't have to apply `;` in Swift and you can use optional check by `if-let` to check if your variable has value while parsing the JSON response as following:

```
    HTTP.GET(url, parameters: [], headers: headers) { response in
        do {
            let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: response.data, options: []) as? [String: Any]
            var accounts = [Account]()
            if let accountsDict = json?["data"] as? [[String: String]] {
                accounts = accountsDict.map { dict -> Account in
                    return Account(name: dict["tenant"]!, geolocation: dict["geolocation"]!)
                }
            }
            completion(accounts)
        } catch {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
            completion(nil)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, thanks to the comments I found out how to to this, using `JSONSerialization` was a bad idea in swift, at is an Objective-C lib and swifts has its own `JSONDecode` that does it all in a simpler way

I was struggling with its types as well as it needs to decode to a `Decodable` object, so I couldn't use the generic array/dicts we would use in obj-c, so I had to create a struct for the response

```
struct Pagination :Decodable{
    var data : Array<Account>;
}
```

that has just the data variable that is what then matches to the Account

with that, the POST become really simple

```
    HTTP.GET(url, parameters: [], headers: headers) { response in
        do {
            let jsonDecoder = JSONDecoder()
            let accounts = try jsonDecoder.decode(Pagination.self, from: response.data)                
            completion(accounts.data);
        }catch{
            print(error.localizedDescription)
            completion(nil);
        }            
    }
```

Thank you!!

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend you to check out and implement [AlamoFire](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire), [PromiseKit](https://github.com/mxcl/PromiseKit) and [SwiftyJSON](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON) those 3 Swift libraries will make your life super easy because you can make Promises, HTTP requests, and then parse your JSON in fewer lines of code, it has easier readability and will save you lots of time, here is an example, using your code as reference:

```
import AlamoFire
import SwiftyJson
import PromiseKit

func DownloadDataAndParseJSON() {

let headers = ["headerParameter": parameter]
let dictionary = [String:String]

Alamofire.request(url, method: .get, headers: headers).responseJSON { response in
    let json = JSON(response.result.value as Any)

    if let items = json.array {
        for item in items{

            let name = item["tenant"].string ?? " "
            let geolocation = item["geolocation"].string ?? " "

            dictionary.updateValue(geolocation, forKey: name)
       }
     }
   }
 }
```

See how you can turn the parsed value to a string with `.string` and also you can use the `??` parameter to add an optional default value in case the JSON throws a `nil` value, and in case you want to use a specific type like in this 'Account' scenario you can easily add it to the existing methods.